# Neo4j data export gets SocketTimeoutException from jersey client

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, jersey-client

I have 3 large neo4j databases (1 million records each) and I need to combine them all together.

I decided to export data from each Neo4j into json files and then load it into new one.

I have problem exporting that data.

If I just enumerate all nodes, the process is tooking to long (around 10 ms per node). I have tried a CYPHER instead:

```
String cypher = "MATCH (n) RETURN n";
if (offset > 0)
    cypher += " SKIP " + offset;
cypher += " LIMIT " + MAX_COMMANDS;

offset += MAX_COMMANDS;

QueryResult<Map<String, Object>> nodes = engine.query(cypher, null);
if (!nodes.iterator().hasNext()) 
    break;

for (Map<String, Object> row : nodes) {
    RestNode node = (RestNode) row.get("n");

    // export code here
}
```

And by this I have achieved a speed of 0.17 ms per node. But, then program has exported about 700k nodes, the program has crashed with  Read timed out.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I have tried to reduce the MAX_COMMANDS constant, but it doesn't help.

Is there a way to increase this timeout? Or is there a more efficient way to export data from Neo4j?

I'm using java-rest-binding 2.0 library and accesing Neo4j server via REST

Thanks and Happy Australia Day

Comment: Solved that by using embedded neo4j.

Comment: Or use the JDBC driver which is also faster and streams results.